# Cygwin mkpasswd giving The format of the specified domain name is invalid

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-sshd

While trying to finish Cygwin config and running `mkpasswd -l -d` and mkgroup, it fails with the following error

```
$ mkpasswd -l -u sorins -d /etc/passwd
sorins:unused:1012:513:sorins,U-JIRA\sorins,S-1-5-21-1179867521-3364476509-4149538525-1012:/home/sorins:/bin/bash
mkpasswd (87): [1212] The format of the specified domain name is invalid.
```

I tried even this option:

```
$ mkpasswd -l /etc/passwd
mkpasswd (374): [123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is in                                                               correct.
```

- JIRA is the computer name and sorins is a Local Administrator
- This machine is part of domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
mkpasswd -l -u sorins -d > /etc/passwd
```

i.e. redirect output to `/etc/passwd`

Comment: In fact the solution was to run only with `mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd` - even if this is on a domain but the user was on local computer.